# What does PHP's mb_internal_encoding actually do?

Tags: php, string

[According to the PHP website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) it does this:

> encoding is the character encoding name used for the HTTP input
>   character encoding conversion, HTTP output character encoding
>   conversion, and the default character encoding for string functions
>   defined by the mbstring module. You should notice that the internal
>   encoding is totally different from the one for multibyte regex.

Can someone please explain this in simpler terms?

1. HTTP input character encoding conversion
2. HTTP output character encoding conversion
3. default character encoding for string functions
4. What is meant by “internal encoding is totally different from the one for multibyte regex”?

My guess is that

1. means GET and POST are treated as that encoding.
2. means it outputs to that encoding.
3. means it uses that encoding for all multibyte string functions.
4. I have no idea about. Why would regex be different to normal string functions?

If point 2 is correct would you need to do:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

If I understand 3 correctly does that mean if you do:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')
```

You don't need to do:

```
mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');
```

Just:

```
mb_strtolower($str);
```

I did read on another SO post that mb_strtolower($str) should no be trusted and that you need to set the encoding for each multibyte string function. Is this true?

Comment: No, it's false. http://php.net/mb_strtolower   string mb_strtolower ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mbstring extension added the glorious idea (`</sarcasm>`) to automatically convert all incoming data and all output data from some encoding to another. See [mbstring HTTP Input and Output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.http.php). It's configured with the `mbstring.http_input` ini setting and by using the `mb_output_handler`. `mb_internal_encoding` influences this conversion. IMO you should leave those settings off and never touch them; I have yet to find any problem that can elegantly be solved by this and it sounds like a terrible idea overall to have implicit encoding conversions going on. Especially if it's all controlled via one global flag (`mb_internal_encoding`) which is used in a variety of different contexts.
So that's 1. and 2.

For 3., yes indeed, `mb_internal_encoding` basically sets the default value for all `mb_` functions which accept an `$encoding` parameter. Essentially it just sets a global variable (internally) which other functions read from, that's all.

The last part refers to the fact that there's a separate [`mb_regex_encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) function to set the internal encoding for `mb_ereg_` functions.

> I did read on another SO post that `mb_strtolower($str)` should no be trusted and that you need to set the encoding for each multibyte string function. Is this true?

I'd agree to this insofar as all global state cannot be trusted. This is pretty trustworthy:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_strtolower($string);
```

However, this is not really:

```
mb_strtolower($string);
```

See the difference? If you rely on global state being set correctly elsewhere, you can never be sure it actually *is* correct. You just need to make a call to some third party library which sets `mb_internal_encoding` to something else without you knowing, and your `mb_strtolower` call will suddenly behave very differently.

Comment: Thanks. 

1, 2. So as long as mbstring.http_input = pass
and mbstring.http_output = pass that's fine?

3. I see what you're saying but then in theory any library could also change things with ini_set. Where do you draw the line?

4. Should I be running mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8')? EUC-JP is the default, whatever that is.

Comment: 1, 2: Yes. 3. Meh, that's a never ending question. :) 4. If you're not using any of the `mb_ereg` functions (and I'm not sure when you would prefer them over `preg_`), leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer. :-) By the way, do you know what EUC-JP is?

Comment: It's a Japanese encoding.

Comment: Weird that it defaults to that. Does that not cause problems?

Comment: Based on anecdotal evidence it appears to me that PHP's encoding facilities largely grew out of a need to support some Japanese developers... Total stab into the dark as to why that may be a default...

Comment: EUC-JP (Extended Unix Code) has ASCII as subset. That said, unless you wander outside of ASCII, you wouldn't notice any difference.