# Understanding character encoding in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am struggling at understanding character encoding in PHP.

Consider the following script (you can run it [here](https://3v4l.org/e58pn)):

```
$string = "\xe2\x82\xac";

var_dump(mb_internal_encoding());
var_dump($string);
var_dump(unpack('C*', $string));
$utf8string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
var_dump($utf8string);
var_dump(unpack('C*', $utf8string));

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

var_dump($string);
var_dump($utf8string);
```

I have a string, actually the € character, represented with its unicode code points. Up to `PHP 5.5` the used internal encoding is `ISO-8859-1`, hence I think that my string will be encoded using this encoding. With `unpack` I can see the bite representation of my string, and it corresponds to the hexadecimal codes I use to define the string.

Then I convert the encoding of the string to `UTF-8`, using `mb_convert_encoding`. At this point the string displays differently on the screen and its byte representation changes (and this is expected).

If I change the `PHP` internal encoding also to `UTF-8`, I'd expect `utf8string` to be displayed correctly on the screen, but this doesn't happen.

What I am missing?

Comment: Are you running this in a browser? That will make its own choice about character encoding and you'd be better off entity escaping the offending character.

Comment: Add a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the `<head>` to make sure the browser is also expecting UTF8

Comment: All strings in PHP are treated as binary strings, and `mb_internal_encoding()` affects literally nothing other than how other `mb_*` functions work. You also can't output both ISO-8859 and UTF8 within the same document and expect anything sane to happen regardless of what program is generating the output.

Answer (score 2):

The script you show doesn't use any non-ascii characters, so its internal encoding does not make any difference. `mb_internal_encoding` does convert your data on output. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653119/what-does-phps-mb-internal-encoding-actually-do) will tell you more about how it works; it will also tell you it's better not to use it.

The three-byte string `$string` in your code is the UTF-8 representation of the Euro symbol, not its "unicode code point" (which is 2 bytes wide, like all common Unicode characters: `0x20ac`).

Does this clear up the behavior you see?

Answer (score 1):

You started with a string that is the `utf-8` representation of the Euro symbol. If you run `echo($string)` all versions of PHP produce the three bytes you put in `$string`. How they are interpreted by the browser depends on the character set specified in the `Content-Type` header. If it is `text/html; charset=utf-8` then you get the Euro sign in the rendered page.

Then you do the wrong move. You call [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) with only two arguments. This lets PHP use the current value of its internal encoding used by the `mb_string` extension for the the third argument (`$from_encoding`). Why?

For PHP 5.6 and newer, the default value returned by [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) is `utf-8` and the call to `mb_convert_encoding()` is a no-op.

But for previous versions of PHP, the default value returned by `mb_internal_encoding()` is `iso-8859-1` and it doesn't match the encoding of your string. Accordingly, `mb_convert_encoding()` interprets the bytes of `$string` as three individual characters and encodes them using the rules of `utf-8`. The outcome is obviously wrong.

Btw, if you initialize `$string` with `'€'` you get the same output on all PHP versions (even on PHP 4, iirc).